# Can somebody help me to create a static sidebar in two column layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Please help me to make this right sidebar static when the user starts scrolling. I am new to responsive type webdesign. I tried to use the "position:fixed" property, but I dont know its feasibility in responsive design. Please help me.
This is the link http://the-bootstrap.obenland.it/page-with-comments/

Comment: So, What is the problem?

Comment: @syedmohsin :need to make the right sidebar sticky just like http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/02/16/google-hosts-glass-foundry-in-sf-and-nyc-giving-developers-early-access-to-its-wearable-computers/?fromcat=all

Comment: @user632347 can you please check the solution I provided and let me know if you get stuck ..Thanks

Comment: @Shail : when I add the fixed property the sidebar get positioned to top left of the page over the logo image.

Comment: @user632347 let us know if it helped

Comment: @user632347 check the new class fixed with right:88px; will fix the issue you had

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSfiddle for you -- [JSfiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/U8HGz/897/)

Create a class like this :-

```
.fixed {

          position:fixed;
          right:88px; /*insert this aswell*/
       }
```

And use it  with the sidebar section like below .

```
<section role="complementary" class="widget-area span4 fixed" id="secondary">
```

Comment: when I add the fixed property the sidebar get positioned to top left of the page over the logo image.

Comment: You will have to position the other sections to position:absolute;

Comment: can you give a quick sample

Comment: I can make it work if the sidebar is on left side. But in my theme its on right side. So how to fix rightsidebar issue?

Comment: i have created a new jsfiddle with right side bar fixed .. check again plz

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24657/discussion-between-shail-and-user632347)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to maintain the Responsive Web Design principles, simply applying position:fixed won't do the trick. If you want it to work nicely on smaller screens, you'll have to have conditional code. It'll have to be fixed on a "normal" screen, and you'll need to remove the class when the screen gets "too small". You'll also have to decide what "normal" and "too small" mean for you. See here for an example:

http://home.edgemontgeek.com/dev/stackoverflow/14919523/

Keep in mind that you'll also need to control for screen height. If the window isn't big enough to fit the fixed content, they won't be able to see it. You could consider having two columns that can be scrolled separately.

Comment: Checking, You are setting the right as zero. In the theme I referred its is not in the extreme right.

Comment: It's an example that you can build from. In this case, it seems like you'll build in a "right: 50px".   :D

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
.fixed{
left:0;
position:fixed;
top:Height_of_logo;
}
```

This will create a sidebar that leaves space for logo on top, but if you want the sidebar to slide up when user scrolls down and then stick when logo is out of scope then i'd suggest you to use Jquery plugin like this one

http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-stick-em

This site has very good documentation along with demo.